# Service Bus for Windows Server Certificate Cannot be Verified

Tags: c#, x509certificate, servicebus

Using [Service Bus for Windows Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193022%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

I get the following Exception.

> Message=The X.509 certificate CN=*********** is not in the trusted
>   people store. The X.509 certificate CN=******** chain building failed.
>   The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be
>   verified. Replace the certificate or change the
>   certificateValidationMode. The signature of the certificate cannot be
>   verified.

I am tring to connect to a Service Bus on another computer from my Dev Box

Here is the code from the console app I am using.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
   new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;

NamespaceManager namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.Create();
MessagingFactory messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.Create();

if (namespaceManager.QueueExists(QueueName))
{    
    namespaceManager.DeleteQueue(QueueName);    
}
namespaceManager.CreateQueue(QueueName);

string QueueName = "ServiceBusQueueSample";                       
QueueClient myQueueClient = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(QueueName);

BrokeredMessage sendMessage = new BrokeredMessage("Hello World !");   
myQueueClient.Send(sendMessage); <---- !!!Exception!!!
```

I exported the certs from the Service Bus Server
   Using: Get-SBAutoGeneratedCA
    AutoGeneratedCA.cer
    AutoGeneratedCA.cr1

I then imported both files useing the default settings to my dev box.

I have added the following items to my app.config.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior >
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication  certificateValidationMode="None" 
                                                       revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <microsoft.identityModel>    
   <service>       
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None"    />
   </service>    
  </microsoft.identityModel>
```

I am able to Successfully authenticate and check if a Queue exists and delete it then create a new one.

While looking for a solution I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuremanagement/thread/35019411-afe4-4a7d-a864-c85199400092) 
Suggesting that there was a problem with the revocation server, since I also imported the Certificate Revocatin List I am not seeing that this is my problem

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534836/x-509-chain-building-failed-when-connecting-to-the-appfabric):
Which linked to this blog [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/03/14/394513.aspx#6648507):
I followed the suggestion without any success.

This Blog [Post](http://blogs.breeze.net/mickb/2012/01/31/AzureServiceBusFixingTheDreadedTheX509CertificateCNservicebuswindowsnetChainBuildingFailedError.aspx):
Suggest that settng the revocationMode="NoCheck" has no affect on this issue and his solution was to spoof the  Certificate Revocation List

This Blog [Post](http://zamd.net/2010/10/05/web-services-federation-with-acs-v2/):
Suggest added the endpoint behavior to disable certificateValidationMode, I did and I still get the error.

Note: When I host the Service Bus on my Dev Machine everything works find.

Any suggestion that I have not tried?

Comment: Another approach that __will__ solve this problem but has security implications:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39415887/5869

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that I was not importing the Certificates correctly...

I followed these instructions and everything worked..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj192993(v=azure.10).aspx

I guess Right Clicking and Installing the certificate put them in the wrong place.

Comment: It is important to put the .cer file to the computer's trusted certificate authorities list. By default it goes in the user's list.